# How do I remove scrollbars from Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, netbook

I'm using a netbook and would like to have as much of my screen real-estate as possible for browsing. I have scroll zones on my trackpad and a scroll wheel on my mouse, so I don't really need scrollbars. Is there any way to get rid of them?

I didn't see anything in Tools -> Options, so I'm guessing it'll be a registry hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, I don't think you can disable the scroll bars system-wide in Internet Explorer 8.

You might be able to get a Grease monkey script (thats if it is available for IE8) that would remove the scroll bars, but there definitely is not a 'built-in' option for this. Some quick Googling came up with [this](http://userstyles.org/styles/9425) (although I am not sure if it would work with IE8)

Answer (score 3):

A scrollbar is a part of the control for showing the page content.  If the content is larger than the space available, the scrollbar will show.  I'm pretty sure there's no way around that.

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce their width in the Display Control Panel. This will affect all scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

if IE is like Firefox, and you can edit the 'default' CSS for all web pages, you could add

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But I'm not sure how'd you go about injecting this. Maybe by hacking a DLL?